# What PCL should I use to build a Xamarin mvvmcross app

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, mvvmcross, setup-project

I am new in `mvvmcross` and I want start to developing an app using this framework but I don't know which PCL should I use and how to mount my solution.

In some videos people uses *C# -> windows -> PCL*, and then add android, ios  projects one by one, but all the videos are too old.

I want to know if there are a newer (better) way to create my solution to use mvvmcross and xamarin.

Beacuse in VSCommunity 2015 see there are a cross-platform option, should I use this?

One more question, how can I fix the *.Core*, in the solution name? And the others *.Ios, .Droid*? If I create my project with *name.Core* all others projects become: *name.Core.Ios, name.Core.Droid*

It will make me in trouble when i have to use the namespace ?

The options?:

Using cross-platform
[image]

Using the old windows -> pcl like in videos
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [mvvmcross addin for Visual studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JimBobBennett.MvvmCrossforVisualStudio) by JimBobBennett.

`tools` > `Extensions and Updates` > click `Online` > search for "Mvvmcross for visual studio"

then create a new project like so :
[image]

It will give a template that will create a solution with this structure:
[image]

Then just delete the projects you dont need.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/jimbobbennett/MvvmCross-VisualStudioAddIn) to the source code for that plugin if you want to take a look